# Does python class special method require special name?

Tags: python, class

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.char=name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.char

>>> spok=Dog("dsakj")
>>> print(spok)
dsakj       

class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

>>> spok=Dog("akjds")
>>> print(spok)
akjds

class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def __info__(self):
        return self.name

>>> spok=Dog("dnask")
>>> print(spok)
<__main__.Dog object at 0x0000000002FF5320>
```

The only thing changed in the third is the name then it didn't work out.

Comment: Please don't accidentally format it correctly. We might erroneously be able to understand what you want to ask.

Comment: Why is this surprising? To turn a custom object into a string, Python calls the special method `__str__`, yes. All special magic methods have a fixed name.

Comment: Um, yes.  That's why it's "special".

Comment: Peripheral to the problem, but still relevant: You have been mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. Don't do that. Configure your editor to always use 4 space characters for each indentation level. Otherwise, you're setting yourself up for hard-to-find errors.

Comment: Here is a good introduction to Python's double-underscore "magic methods": http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

Answer (score 3):

When you print an object, the 'toString' method (`__str__`) gets called implicitly. Without that method (which you are missing in your third example), Python does not know how to convert an arbitrary object to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Special methods are called by functions. If you want to write your own function info you could make like this:

```
def info(obj):
   if hasattr(obj,'__info__'):
       return obj.__info__()
   raise Exception('Not informable object')

class Dog:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

   def __info__(self):
      print 'Informational note about class named : %s'%self.name

sparky = Dog('sparky')
info(sparky)

'Informational note about class named : sparky'
```

**edit for informational sake**

The open nature of python allows you to do things like that even when you have coding conventions like this one [PEP 0008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles), Thanks @Daniel for the advice

Comment: PEP8 specifically [recommends against](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) using double-underscore names for anything other than Python's own documented interfaces.

Comment: you must do not things like that, but you can do things like that, just telling that you are able to do so, but it is important to note that is not recommended too, thanks